# WPF Binding to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have list of Tabs where Tab is:

```
public class Tab
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set}
  public List<country> Country {get; set;} 

}
```

Now, I want to bind it  to two comboboxes:
First combobox is ok, but at second I want to display country list.

```
 <custom:ComboBox  Title="Tab" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs, Mode=TwoWay}"
               ValuePath="Id"
               Value="{Binding Model.Id, Mode=TwoWay}"
               DisplayPath="Name"
               IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"/>


 <custom:ComboBox  Title="Country" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding Model.Country, Mode=TwoWay}"
                ItemsSource="{}" 
                DisplayPath="CountryName"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

How to set ItemsSource at second combobox when I know Id.
Is another way than create varible, like selectedList and then bind to it?

EDIT

[image]

I am creating new dialogbox and I'm  sending model with tab id and dialogbox context have tab list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your first `ComboBox` a name with `x:Name="FirstComboBox"` and change your `ItemsSource` of the second `ComboBox` `to ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=FirstComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.Country}"`.

Just a hint: When binding collections in xaml use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`.

Comment: The second combobox is reloaded only when I manualy selected value from first combobox. When I binding automatically, second combobox is empty then I must select value from combobox first and then second Combox have values. Should I use UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged or something

Comment: To update second combobox i must click into first. How to update second combobox automatically?

Comment: What do you mean with automatically?

Comment: i mean that  I binding Id to combobox value path and its ok but second combobox is empty and than i must return click to first combobox and now second combobox have values.

Comment: Is something selected in the first combobox when your second is empty? If yes: How did you selected an entry in the first combobox?

Comment: I am creating new dialogbox and I'm sending model with tab id and dialogbox context have tab list.

Comment: So when you dialog is shown the first ComboBox has a selected entry and the second not?

Comment: I have 2 modes: edit and add . When I click edit then first combobox is selected. I use property Change at my model and if sometthing change , tab or country then I update lists

Comment: Maybe it would help if you post the code where it's not working.